# How to reference glut32.dll in VisualStudio2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, dll, glut

I am having a problem referencing Glut or FreeGlut in a Visual Studio C# Project. I am using OpenTK Framework (which works fine) but I just can't get Glut running. So far I have moved all files Glut requires to work to these directories, as most tutorials describe:

```
glut.h: ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\GL\’
glut32.lib: ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\’
glut32.dll: ‘C:\Windows\System32\’
```

For 64-bit machines, you will want to do this:

```
glut32.dll: ‘C:\Windows\SysWOW64\’
```

When I start VisualS tudio with my C# project, I just can't use Glut as I would use OpenTK through writing "using Glut;" or using System.Glut;

Whenever I try to set a reference on glut32.dll within the project folder, I get an error saying that:

> glut32.dll is not a valid assembly or COM-component. What am I doing
>   wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you just using what is built into the `.NET` framework already?

Comment: I would like to use functions like glutSolidSphere(); and others which the .NET framework does not contain.

Comment: If glut32.dll is not a .NET assembly, and not a COM component, then you will probably have to access its functionality through P/Invoke.

Comment: So far I found out that freeglut would only work with C++. My current solution is to use the Tao.FreeGlut (which translates to C#) alongside with OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL. Still the freeglut.dll + Tao.FreeGlut.dll have to be in the C:\windows\system32 folder. Can be closed :)